# How to use generics on interface property

Tags: typescript

How does one propogate generics on an `interface` at a property level when referencing other generic types?  Hopefully, the code below clarifies what I'm asking:

```js
type Fn<T> = (arg: T)=>void

interface A {
    // the functionality I'd like to replicate:
    fn1<R>(arg: R): void,
    // How does one use a generic here - similar to `fn1` above, without adding it to the entire interface as per B below?
    fn2<S>: Fn<S>
}

interface B<S>{
    // I don't want to add the generic to the entire interface as it is only applicable to a single property
    fn: Fn<S>
}
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgCoD4oF4oAoCGAnAcwC4okBKdFANwHsBLAEwFgAoVuuYCPAMxwGNoAQSgBvVlElQA9NKjAAFtB4BXOP2B0acHABs6oKAEkA5Ayj6A1tGA0oeCGH38cXIhKk84ARgQAlFFxCEj8yElpGABoPSVkoAAkaAHcoBhoIAGcobWgVDOgcKAIIOG46figlBygAWigMugBbOl18eTsvIwYAGTprJBoAUUaVVq4oHAAjGioISKgkgwUaFWAJhgYOAigDdvklKBLNao4uXgECrMg8KAAhKEmIXWSAfhioLwAmBABlFBJ4L8UKwAL6sdicbh8QR3IHiFhSGRyIypbQmNZJHCcPY4Db7aDFUp4cp7RTQI50E6Q84wnBZXZ0LLaXQgCZgJzlKa6Gx2QoNOAEblQMB4GjXUDvLwAxB-UFAA)

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. At some point in the code, there needs to be one that specifies the concrete type. Where do you envision that to be at? If you don't specify interface B<S>, there is no way the Fn will know what type it should infer, **within the interface

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100, thank you for your comment. and likely you are right that this may not be possible.  The generic type should resolve itself in exactly the same way `fn1` does in the code example.  To DRY my code I would rather use a generic than repeat the generic definition multiple times.

Comment: Not currently possible, sorry.  See the answer to the linked question for more info